# Can I earn achievements that aren't specifically multiplayer in Civ 5?

Tags: achievements, civilization-5

I played a few multiplayer games with a friend this weekend against computer opponents and noticed that I didn't receive an achievement I know I should have earned. It was "Win a game as the Americans on any difficulty" and I was for sure playing as the Americans. The only reason I can think it might not have counted is that we were teamed up against the computers who were free-for-all.

We played two normal games before that, and I'm curious if those even counted towards my achievement progress. There is at least one multiplayer-specific achievement I earned then, so you would think everything else would count as well, right?

Comment: I'd post as an answer but I have no reference, however I'm about 70% certain that many of the achievements are single-player only. I've played a few multiplayer games with my friends and haven't gotten any achievements for either despite fulfilling the stated requirements (winning with nations / on difficulties, mostly). Try an FFA in multiplayer and see if you can unlock an achievement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Playing with in-game modifications enabled will disable the ability to get achievements](http://forums.2kgames.com/showthread.php?88768-Mods-Disable-Acheivments). I haven't found anything stating that simply playing multiplayer will prevent you from getting achievements but the achievements in Civilisation 5 are very specifically worded.

As you earned a multiplayer achievement during your play time I would go with you (obviously) having modifications off but the single-player achievements only taking effect in single player.

Update: found something, [this is an archived post on the Steam forums complaining about lack of features in Civilisation 5 multiplayer](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-1572383.html).

> 9) No achievements except for the one "Last Man Standing' multiplayer achievement. Even if you beat a game with a leader you've never played before you won't get the achievement. All but one are only for single player :-(